# AWS Lambda acces to EC2 mssql timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I tryed to use a function lambda to connect to my mssql in EC2 windows instances..

But i got the error message like :
"errorMessage": "2023-01-03T09:16:22.241Z 16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 5.01 seconds"

ofc i changed the expiration time but it's not work.. always same error

What does the error message mean?

I upload pyodbc in lambda Layers, and test the connection with:

```
import pyodbc

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    server = 'servername'
    port = '1433'
    database =  'db'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'pwd' # ideally put this in a SecretsManager secret instead of directly in the code
    connection = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server},{port};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """
        select @@version
    """

    cursor.execute(query)

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0])
```

Full error message:
Status: error

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-01-03T09:16:22.241Z 16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 5.01 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST
2023-01-03T09:16:22.241Z 16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 5.01 seconds

END RequestId: 16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
REPORT RequestId: 16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  Duration: 5007.24 ms    Billed Duration: 5000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB  Init Duration: 145.43 ms

Request ID
16863c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Did you add the Lambda to the VPC of the EC2 instance, and make sure that security mechanisms such as IAM, SG, NACL etc. are set up for communication to go through?

Comment: Yes, i added the same VPC on my lambda than EC2.
And I have a full acces IAM

Comment: You have to provide security group configuration for both rds and lambda.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks, but both have same VPC, same subnet and same security group which allow 1433 port's acces ... 
(I have not rds, but a EC2 Windows instance)